# How add image to sales_order_grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, grid, sales-order, image

I need to add custom image into `sales_order_grid` for each order.

when checkout, I need to get custom image and stored to `sales_order_grid` for each order.

I know add custom column to `sales_order_grid` and `sales_order` and save custom field value.  But i need to add Custom Image.

My question:

1. which column type I need to use like `TYPE_TEXT, TYPE_INTEGER` While create a custom column for to view Image in `sales_order` and `sales_order_grid`.
2. I have Custom image Full Url, how to save this value to table and viewed as a image.
3. How magento2 get image in `catalog/product` grid view.